# Two list on a single flutter screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm fresh new to flutter, so I'm trying to merge two different flutter examples into a single screen.

What I mean is I want to be able to have a vertical gridView (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists), then under it I want to insert a horizontal list (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list). I tryed inserting both on a Widget list but that doesn't do anything at all.

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you have both your `GridView` and your `Horizontal List` declared and initallized properly as `grid` and `list`. What you can do is create a ListView like the following:

```
Widget buildBody() {
return ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: <Widget>[
    grid,
    list
  ],
);
}
```

Then you can call this when you initialize your scaffold here:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('AppBar'),
  ),
  body: buildBody(),
);
```

To add space in between the `GridView` and the `Horizontal List` just add a `Padding` Widget in between them in the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a list and grid to scroll together in single screen. I suggest you take a look at `SliverList` & `SliverGrid`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM

Basic example is

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Slivers'),
      ),
      body: _buildSlivers(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSlivers() {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverGrid.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children: _gridItems(),
        ),
        SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
          );
        }))
      ],
    );
  }
```

This would generate the following results.

[image]

Flutter docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers